# Background image doesn't appear on HTML email Dark Mode

Tags: html, html-email, darkmode

I am designing HTML email template which look fine on majority devices, iOS's and browsers except **Outlook Office 365 on Windows 10** Dark Mode.

The problem is that my background image doesn't appear, instead background colour becomes dark. I have a logo on my background and since  it's dar too - I can't see it.

This is how it looks on **Outlook Office 365 on Windows 10** Dark Mode:
[image: This is how it looks on Outlook Office 365 on Windows 10 Dark Mode]

I would like to display my background image, but if it's impossible - either to change the background colour to light (which is against the Dark Mode rules, I guess), or display white version of the logo (the different image). But the changes should only be made on **Outlook Office 365 on Windows 10** Dark Mode

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It would help to get screenshots of what happens, and what is expected

Answer (score 0):

Try something other than .svg. For example.png.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for the response an I'm sorry, English is not my native language, so probably I wrote it unclear. I use the .png file for the image, but I've also tried .svg as an option. 

I also edited my original post and added the print screen example. Hope it would be more clear that is the issue i try dealing with. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Windows doesn't have the controls we need to do that. The best you can do is to edit the image by adding a white stroke to it, or white shadow. This will not show on light mode (assuming your normal background is white--if not, use your normal background colour).

e.g. this white shadow will not show on light mode:

[image: Litmus logo with white shadow around black text]

See https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers/#design for more information about all this.